# Using FOR loop to fill in a data from in R (code review)

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

So my objective is to fill in the last column of a data frame with values. The data frame is [343,8].  I wrote up a solution to this but it is not working and I am curious as to why my idea would not work:

```
result = vector(length = 3)

for(i in 1:343){
  for(j in 1:3){
    result[j] = combos[i:j]
  }
  combos$prize[i] = score(result)
}
```

The name of the larger data frame is "combos", the last column of the data frame is "prize".

My attempt was to create the empty vector "result", fill it with the values from the first three columns of "combos", then apply a function that I created called "score" on to the "result" vector, and finally fill in the the specific entry in the "combo" data frame with the value obtained from "score".

My version doesn't work, but there is a solution in the textbook which works:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(combos)) {
 symbols <- c(combos[i, 1], combos[i, 2], combos[i, 3])
 combos$prize[i] <- score(symbols)
 }
```

Now I don't see much difference between what the author did and myself. Yes he didn't use a second FOR loop, but the procedure to arrive at the final result seems consistent.

With that being said, what is it that I did not do correct?

**EDIT**  This is a copy of the *score* function that I am calling in my for loop:

```
score = function(symbols) {

# identify case
same = symbols[1] == symbols[2] & symbols[2] == symbols[3]
bars = symbols %in% c("B","BB","BBB")

# get prize
if (same) {
payouts = c("DD" = 100, "7" = 80, "BBB" = 40, "BB" = 25, "B" = 10, "C" = 10, 
"0" = 0)
prize = unname(payouts[symbols[1]])

} else if (all(bars)){
prize = 5 

} else {
cherries = sum("C" == symbols)
prize = c(0,2,5)[cherries + 1]
}

# adjust for diamonds
diamonds = sum("DD" == symbols)
prize * 2 ^(diamonds)

}
```

Comment: `score` returns an integer value ?

Comment: @yolo yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is with how you are creating your symbols "vector". Because a data.frame is really considered a type of "list" in R, what you are doing is assigning a 3-element list to your symbols variable. Hence, you will need to unlist this before you can make the comparisons you are seeking.

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(combos)) {
     symbols <- unlist(c(combos[i, 1], combos[i, 2], combos[i, 3]))
     combos$prize[i] <- score(symbols)
    }
```

This should solve your issue though I cannot exactly test without the combos data.frame but I assume this is your issue just looking at the code and the error message you received. Good luck!

Comment: it worked!!!......so I'm curious as to why the author would provide this sort of solution without initially introducing the >>unlist function......

Comment: Yes I’m not sure why they provided an answer like that unless it’s a really old text and something in base R changed. If this answers your question please accept as an answer or if you want me to clarify anything please let me know! It’s may be because using for loops in R are pretty inefficient and they should be teaching lapply. Again best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `i:j` in `combos[i:j]` returns a vector from i to j. Try to run `5:7` for example. So you're doing some 'weird' subsetting with `combos[i:j]`. You probably want that to be `combos[i, j]` which returns the (i, j)th entry of combos.

`combos[i:j]` returns the i'th through j'th entries of `combos` (which I assume is a numeric matrix). In R, matrices are stored in a column-major order, so the your intial subsetting returns the corresponding entries and might 'span the columns'. Take a look a the following to illustrate:

```
x <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)

print(x)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]    2    4    6

print(x[2:3])
#[1] 2 3

print(x[2,3])
#[1] 6
```

So, does

```
result = vector(length = 3)
for(i in 1:343){
  for(j in 1:3){
    result[j] = combos[i, j]
  }
  combos$prize[i] = score(result)
}
```

work?

Comment: It is a lot closer to working. Thanks you, I didn't see the simple mistake. Now I'm having a little issue with the function "score" I'm calling. I get the error: "Error in symbols[1] == symbols[2] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented"

Comment: Hm, that seems odd. If `nrow(combos)` indeed is 343 then the two are equivalent from what I can tell. Please make sure you are running it in a 'clean' R session. Does the error persist? If it does, I'm afraid I/we need to know more about your data and `score` to help you.

Comment: I still got the same error when I restarted R. I can paste what my >score function does. It just takes a vector of three elements, each of which is a character string, and then compares the values. I'll paste the function above.